# Is "better" to use Generics (?), Object or separate the classes?

Tags: java, object, generics

I have a wrapper class that contain a `list<Car>` and some methods which return a `Car` object.

I need another class that would contain a `list<Bike>` and the same methods with the same implementation but of course different kind of return type (`Bike`).

I was thinking that maybe in order to avoid repeating code and avoid one class I could use a `list<?>` or a `list<Object>`, but then I would need to do some cast when returning objects.

Which one do you think is more efficient?

Comment: I think, You are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Why not make the class generic? Or use a generic base class.

Comment: Have a class `Vehicle`, `VehicleList<T extends Vehicle>` and make `Car` and `Bike` `extends Vehicle`. Then you can use `VehicleList<Bike> bikes;` and `VehicleList<Car> cars;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending on my comment, you could have the following structure to fully make use of generics.

An abstract parent class

```
abstract class Vehicle {
    ...
}
```

A generic, bounded list container class

```
class VehicleList<T extends Vehicle> {
    private final List<T> vehicles; // Or any other way you want to hold your data
    ...
}
```

And concrete classes inheriting from `Vehicle`

```
class Car extends Vehicle {
    ...
}

class Bike extends Vehicle {
    ...
}
```

Then, wherever you want to have a list of `Vehicle`s, you can use it like the following:

```
VehicleList<Car> cars = ...;
VehicleList<Bike> bikes = ...;
```

Comment: I agreed, but instead of abstract class can we have interface.. so that sub classes have option extends any other classes

Comment: Probably he didn't suggest an interface because the implementation of the methods it's exactly the same for every "child" class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics on classes too.

So you could set your class as

```
public class MyClass<T> {
private T t;
.....
```

this way you could write generic methods

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency this doesn't matter. You won't notice a single cast, which is a very fast operation, and generics already often do casts under the hood.

However, for this scenario

> I have a class (it's kinda of a wrapper) which contain a `list<Car>` and some methods which return a `Car` object.
>
> Now I should make another class which would contain a `list<Bike>` and the same methods with the same implementation but of course different kind of return type (`Bike`).

it's more reasonable not to use `List<?>` *or* `List<Object>` but to make your own class generic, possibly bounded.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question of performance.  I think it's about readability, clarity, and understanding.

Your `Car`, `Bike`, etc. works best if they all extend a common base class or interface (e.g. `Vehicle`).

Your class would look like this if you use generics with a base Vehicle interface:

```
public class VehicleRepo<T extends Vehicle> { 
    private List<T> vehicles;
    private T vehicle;

    T getVehicle() { return this.vehicle; }
}
```